# Webservice-Client: Common approach with Spring WS, JAXB and just one WSDL file?

Tags: java, web-services, spring, wsdl, jaxb

I would like to use Spring WS to build a Webservice-Client with JAXB for marshalling and unmarshalling the Java classes.

But what I have is just one WSDL file. When I understand it right, I can generate Java classes with JAXB (xjc.exe), which then can be used by me with Spring WS to retrieve the Webservice-Data and send an answer.

But JAXB can only generate Java classes from xsd-schema files. Must I now manually copy those xsd-definitions from within the WSDL file to generate those classes via JAXB? (in my case the WSDL file contains 4 XSD definitions).

Or is there a way to just convert the whole WSDL to Java classes which I can use with Spring WS (I know there is the "wsimport", but it is part of JAX-WS and I think I can't use it in this scenario, right?).

So what is the common approach with Spring WS / JAXB / one WSDL file?

I really would like to get startet with Spring WS and JAXB - thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Please have a look to:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42952387/how-to-set-wsdl-inner-schema-to-jaxb2marshaller-to-validate-each-post-i-wold-mak Reggards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can generate Java classes with JAXB (xbj.exe)

`xjc`, you mean.

> Must I now manually copy those xsd-definitions from within the WSDL file to generate those classes via JAXB?

That's one option, certainly. A more automated approach is to write an XSL transform to extract the schema components into temporary files, and then to run XJC over those. A bit more work, but automation is always good.

> I know there is the "wsimport", but it is part of JAX-WS and I think I can't use it in this scenario, right?

Actually, JAX-WS artifacts are just a decorated form of JAXB. `wsimport` will produce some JAX-WS-specific stuff, plus the standard JAXB artifacts representing the schema components.  You should be able to use the JAXB generated classes for Spring-WS, and ignore the JAX-WS-specific ones.

Comment: Hi skaffman, thanks for your answer, that helped me a lot. For xjc.exe, there is also a flag "-wsdl", but it is marked as experimental. I decided to do it manually for now, but the hint with the XSLT is a good idea.

Comment: > xjc, you mean.

Yes of course, thanks, I edited my question to correct this.