# Consume webservice service in SPRING-WS using wsdl

Tags: spring, web-services, wsdl, spring-ws

I have WSDL with me .eg: /sample/hello?wsdl . I want to invoke the service the webservice by configuring in Spring-ws. I passed this wsdl as parameter to  tags in springconfig.xml. 
Can anyone please tell me how to consume this webservice in Spring-ws.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

### 1. Set up project dependencies

add the following dependencies to the pom file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

### 2. Set up web service application context

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">

    <bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory" />

    <bean id="marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
        <property name="contextPath" value="com.yourcomany.model" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="webServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="messageFactory" />
        <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller"></property>
        <property name="unmarshaller" ref="marshaller"></property>
        <property name="messageSender">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsMessageSender" />
        </property>
        <property name="defaultUri"
            value="http://<hostname>:<portnumber>/sample/hello" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

### 3. Set up model classes which would map to your SOAP request/response objects

For example, if your SOAP request XML looked like

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xxx="http://yourcomapny.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <xxx:InputParameters>
         <xxx:paramONE>1</xxx:paramONE>
      </xxx:InputParameters>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

and your SOAP response XML looked like:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <env:Header>
      ...
   </env:Header>
   <env:Body>
      <xxx:OutputParameters xmlns:xxx="http://yourcompany.com">
         <xxx:paramONE>0</xxx:paramONE>
      </xxx:OutputParameters>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

the corresponding classes (under the package you specified in the marshaller bean: com.yourcompany.model) would be respectively:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = { "paramONE" })
@XmlRootElement(name = "InputParameters", namespace = "http://yourcompany.com")
public class InputParameters {

    @XmlElement(required = true, namespace = "http://yourcompany.com")
    private String paramONE;

    public String getParamONE() {
        return paramONE;
    }

    public void setParamONE(String paramONE) {
        this.paramONE = paramONE;
    }

}
```

and

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = { "paramONE" })
@XmlRootElement(name = "OutputParameters", namespace = "http://yourcompany.com")
public class OutputParameters {

    @XmlElement(required = true, namespace = "http://yourcompany.com")
    private BigDecimal paramONE;

    public BigDecimal getParamONE() {
        return this.paramONE;
    }

    public void setParamONE(BigDecimal paramONE) {
        this.paramONE= paramONE;
    }

}
```

### 4. Add an Object Factory (under package com.yourcompany.model) to create request/response objects

```
@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    public ObjectFactory() {
    }

    public InputParameters createYourRequest() {
        return new InputParameters();
    }

    public OutputParameters createYourResponse() {
        return new OutputParameters();
    }

}
```

### 5. Create a client to consume the service

Interface:

```
public interface YourService {

    BigDecimal getValue(String paramOne);

}
```

Implementation

```
@Component("yourServiceClient")
public class YourServiceClient implements YourService {

    private static final ObjectFactory WS_CLIENT_FACTORY = new ObjectFactory();

    private WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public YourServiceClient(WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate) {
        this.webServiceTemplate = webServiceTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public BigDecimal getValue(String paramOne) {
        InputParameters request = WS_CLIENT_FACTORY
                .createYourRequest();
        request.setParamONE(paramOne);

        OutputParameters response = (OutputParameters) webServiceTemplate
                .marshalSendAndReceive(request);

        return response.getParamONE();
    }

}
```

Comment: I think instead of 'contextPath', please user 'packagesToScan'

Comment: how to send request to different web services? I mean in case you do not want to set the WSDL in the application context.

Comment: 1. Add another webServiceTemplate <bean>; re-use same marshaller/unmarshaller/messageSender; set defaultUri to the URI of the second web service;
2. Add new request and response classes under com.yourcompany.model package;
3. Add methods to ObjectFactory for creating request and response objects of the second web service;
4. Add method to YourService interface and its implementation (Or create a separate interface) to consume the new service.
Bear in mind that because you would now have two instances of WebServiceTemplate you need to distinguish them using something like @Resource

Comment: One slight amendment to my comment above: You can still use a single `WebServiceTemplate` bean and have multiple web service URIs specified in it via `messageSenders` field

Comment: @TaoufikMohdit, very interesting solution, thank you for your complete answer. I have a question: what is the `httpclient` dependency used for? I mean in your proposed solution. Thanks in advance for your time

Comment: @AlvaroPedraza, the `httpclient` dependency is needed by the `messageSender` bean (of type `HttpComponentsMessageSender`). As the `spring-ws-core` POM has the `httpclient` dependency declared with the scope `compile` only, it has to be included explicitly in your own project POM for the dependency to be added to runtime, or it should be already in the container on which you intend to run the application

Answer (score 2):

@Taoufik Mohdit answer is complete!!

To build the input and output objects you can use [Webservice-Client: Common approach with Spring WS, JAXB and just one WSDL file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6730388/webservice-client-common-approach-with-spring-ws-jaxb-and-just-one-wsdl-file) to some how build these objects automatically

Answer (score 0):

Given that this question is still active I thought I would post an update that reflects a number of changes that the recent version of the Spring Web Services framework and Spring in general introduce:

1. The introduction of Spring Boot allows to leverage 'starter' POMs to simplify your Maven configuration. There is a specific `spring-boot-starter-web-services` starter for Spring-WS
2. Instead of specifying Spring configuration files using XML, [Spring JavaConfig](http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/htmlsingle/spring-javaconfig-reference.html) was introduced which provides a type-safe, pure-Java option for configuring Spring.
3. Generation of request/response objects based on a given WSDL file can be automated using Maven plugins. The plugin used by the Spring-WS examples is the `maven-jaxb2-plugin`.

The `WebServiceTemplate` is still the core class for client-side Web service access. For more information you can check this [detailed example on how to consume a web service using Spring-WS starting from a WSDL file](https://codenotfound.com/spring-ws-example.html) that I wrote.