# Convert java based configuration of spring SOAP web serviceexample

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-ws

In "[Consuming a SOAP web service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/)" the configuration is in java style.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller;

@Configuration
public class WeatherConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setContextPath("hello.wsdl");
        return marshaller;
    }

    @Bean
    public WeatherClient weatherClient(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
        WeatherClient client = new WeatherClient();
        client.setDefaultUri("http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx");
        client.setMarshaller(marshaller);
        client.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
        return client;
    }
}
```

I need help to convert this in an xml configuration file.

Is this possible?
Can some one help me?

Comment: refer to chapter 34, spring xml-based configuration, in Spring documentation : http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html

Comment: you can have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18763881/2061273